# Delaying jQuery's handlerOut

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the following jQuery function:

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

Now, I want to delay the "`handlerOut`" part, but I can't seem to get this working. I've tried using `delay()` and `setTimeout()` but they both didn't work. I think it's a syntax thing. Here's my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var menuItem2 = document.getElementById('#menu_item_2');
    var menuItem3 = document.getElementById('#menu_item_3');
    $('#menu_item_2').hover(function () {
        this.style.zIndex = "1";
        menuItem3.style.zIndex = "0";
    });

    $('#menu_item_3').hover(function () {
        this.style.zIndex = "1";
        menuItem2.style.zIndex = "0";
    }, function () {
        $(this).delay(500).style.zIndex = "0";
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="menu_parent2">
            <a href="#music">
                <div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_2">
                    <h5>Music</h5>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Displays my music projects</p>
                </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#contact">
                <div class="menuItem" id="menu_item_3">
                    <h5>Contact</h5>
                    <hr>
                    <p>Displays a contact form</p>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: I think it should be `$(this).delay(500).css({"z-index" : 0})`. And this if you are planning on using jquery, then dont mix it with pure javascript.

Comment: @dvenkatsagar Tried it, still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you provide a html part of your code?

Comment: @dvenkatsagar Added html, the `#menu_item_2` gets slided over `#menu_item_3` using css, which is why I want to change the `z-index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the you should convert it to pure Jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#menu_item_2').hover(function () {
        $(this).css({"z-index":1});
        $("#menu_item_3").css({"z-index":0});
    });

    $('#menu_item_3').hover(function () {
        $(this).css({"z-index":1});
        $("#menu_item_2").css({"z-index":0});
    }, function () {
        $(this).delay(2000).css({"z-index" : 0,"background-color" : "red"});
    });
});
```

Try it out and see if it works.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. But aren't the css() properties supposed to be in quotation marks? So `"z-index" : 0`? If I don't use quotation marks it doesn't get executed properly.

Comment: But consider this as well, you might want to use `queue` if it gives you problems(as @Andrew Brooke suggested).